# Обработка пользовательского ввода с обработкой ошибок ввода в С++. Получение числа от пользователя в консоли

Tags: c++, lambda, cin

Как в С++ запросить у пользователя число с обработкой ошибок ввода и повторным запросом значения, если пользователь ввёл не число?

**Уточняю, что меня не устраивает в любых других методах запроса данных от пользователя** - меня не устраивает, что для того, чтобы нормально такой запрос данных отработал поток `cin` должен быть в идеальном состоянии, в нём не должно быть лишних символов, перед вызовом функции запроса значения все предыдущие вызовы аналогичных функций (если их несколько разных) должны отработать идеально не записав в конец `'\n'` или не оставив после себя символов, так как пользователь написал 5 символов, а выше кто-то с помощью `cin.get()` извлёк только один символ. Нужна универсальная не умирающая от каждого чиха функция. Для этого я придумал тест-кейсы. Зачем всё это нужно? На учёбе у людей какая-то небывалая проблема, у них постоянно проблемы с потоками ввода вывода, после `int n; cin >> n;` и ввода туда символа у них дальше все запросы пролетают махом, то ещё что-то. Нужна неубиваемая функция, которая будет работать при любом раскладе нормально. Вот в `C#` я не знаю, как можно так убить работу программы, там делай что угодно, здесь же "сотни" способов нарушить работу программы.

**Тест-кейсы**:

1. Вызвав функцию ввести не число. `Ожидается`: Повторный запрос ввода значения
2. Вызвав функцию ввести число не входящее в запрашиваемый диапазон. `Ожидается`: Повторный запрос ввода значения
3. Вызвав функцию ввести число, пробел и буквы. `Ожидается`: Повторный запрос ввода значения
4. Вызвав функцию ввести число и пробел. `Ожидается`: Повторный запрос ввода значения
5. Вызвав функцию ввести число входящее в запрашиваемый диапазон. `Ожидается`: Число принято, функция вернула результат
6. После возврата результата функцией и её повторном вызове не выводится два или более раз сообщение и только потом останавливается с ожиданием ввода пользователем. Сообщение всегда выводится строго один раз после успешного срабатывания этой же самой функции ранее.
7. Ввести любое количество символов, превышающее один символ, запросить после этого один символ (`cout << cin.get()`) и вызвать функцию. `Ожидается`: Запрос ввода значения в нормальном режиме без аномалий вроде зависания без запроса значения или требования нажать Enter 2 раза, так как `cin.ignore` ждёт, где ожидалось, что ждать не будет и всё в этом духе.

Формат вызова требуемой функции (название и типы не обязательно именно такие, можно и int). Так же на этом примере можно потестить.

```cpp
// Часть заголовочных файлов может быть нужна для мной выложенных примеров кода в ответе
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    const uint32_t MIN_ARRAY_SIZE = 1u;
    const uint32_t MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 50u;

    const string message = "Введите кол-во элементов в массиве в диапазоне от " +
        to_string(MIN_ARRAY_SIZE) + " до " + to_string(MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) + ": ";

    const uint32_t numberOfValues = 
          getUserInputAsUInt32(message, MIN_ARRAY_SIZE, MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);

    const uint32_t numberOfValues2 = 
          getUserInputAsUInt32(message, MIN_ARRAY_SIZE, MAX_ARRAY_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Внутри `getUserInputAsUInt32` должен быть цикл, который не вернёт управление, пока не введут правильное значение и последующие запросы значений должны срабатывать правильно, а не, к примеру, выводить запрос данных два раза подряд, если пользователь ввёл число, пробел и буквы.

Пока что **лучшее решение**, на мой взгляд, которое проходит все тест-кейсы, кроме #7. Самый надёжный вариант, который возвращает результат, только если ввели значение строго из запрашиваемого диапазона без других лишних символов и пробелов:

```cpp
uint32_t getUserInputAsUInt32(const std::string& message, uint32_t min, uint32_t max)
{
    using namespace std;
    assert(min < max);

    uint32_t number = 0u;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << message;

        string input;
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input.length() == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        const int64_t digitsCount = count_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
            [](unsigned char ch) { return isdigit(ch); });

        if (static_cast<size_t>(digitsCount) == input.length())
        {
            const uint64_t temp = stoull(input);
            if (temp <= numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
            {
                number = static_cast<uint32_t>(temp);
                if (number >= min && number <= max)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870993/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-int-c или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786509/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81

Answer (score 1):

Тут все просто. Диалог с пользователем можно и нужно вести с помощью cout вот так

```
include <iostream>
include <windows.h>
include <stdlib>
include <cstring>  

using namespace std;

 int main (void){
 SetConsoleCP (1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
int a;
cout << "Введите целое число" << endl;
string number;
cin >> number;
a = atoi (number)
```

Обработку ошибок можно делать через цикл вот так

```
 while (a != atoi(namber.c_str())){
 cout << "Ошибка, введите число, пожалуйста" << endl;
 cin >> number;
 a = atoi (number.c_str());
 }
```

Но можно и, мне кажется, правильнее использовать для отлова ошибок специальный блок кода try-catch, он для этого и предназначен в конце концов.

```
 int b;
 cout << "Введите число" << endl; 

 try {
 // в блоке try выполняются действия, которые нужно проверить
 b = atoi(number.c_str());
 // делаем с числом что нужно
 }

 // будем отлавливать стандартные исключения, используя объект класса exception
 catch (const exception & ex){
 // у объектов класса exception есть метод .what，
 // который позволяет получить информацию, о том, что именно пошло не так (на английском)  
 cout << ex.what() << endl;
 cout << "введите целое число";
 cin >> number;
 b = atoi(number.c_str());
 } 
 return 0; 
 }
```

Но в catch естественно можно поместить и свое исключение, например

```
int c;
try{
cout << "Введите целое число"; 
cin >> c;
}
catch (c != atoi(number.c_str())){
cout << "Ошибка, нам нужно число"; 
}
```

Добавляю в ответ случай с пробелами и другими символами. В этом случае использовать string не получится, но можно будет отсечь 
пробелы и буквы с помощью функции strtol

```
long int d;
char [] number;
char *pEnd;
cin >> number;
d = strtol(number, &pEnd);
```

Вывода ошибок в этом случае не нужно

Comment: Что здесь number?

Comment: При запросе значения мне неизвестно, что введёт пользователь, так что у меня нет значения number. Я оформил вопрос в более развёрнутый, с конкретными требованиями к функционалу, сделал это, потому что тут кто-то стремится закрыть вопрос, как дубликат (наверное) или просто как вопрос, на который есть решение. Но решения нет. Все ответы, которые я находил не проходят описанные мной тест кейсы.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ..

Comment: Чуть позже посмотрю. Спасибо.

Comment: `    long int number;
    string input;
    char *pEnd;
    cin >> input;
    number = strtol(input.c_str(), &pEnd, 10);`

Заработало так

Comment: Благодаря вашему ответу появился Пример 3. Правда я использую strtoll, но я хоть нагуглил, что есть такие функции.

Comment: Рад что был Вам полезен.

Answer (score 0):

*Учу С++, искал решение и почти всё, что я находил мне казалось неудобным или были недочёты в плане обработки ошибок. Решил написать свой вариант. Чтобы он не пропал зря, выложу его здесь.*

Приведу в качестве примера 3 функции, одна с применением шаблонов и предиката, вторая полностью повторяет первую, но без шаблонов, а третья самая упрощённая без использования шаблонов и предиката.

Функции из **примера 1** запроса значений от пользователя проходят не все тест кейсы, которые были добавлены мной позже в вопрос.

**Пример 1** Полный код. Проходит НЕ все тест кейсы. Если ввести число, пробел и символ, то после нового запроса значения, если такой запрос зациклен, то он будет выведен на экран 2 раза.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

void pause(const std::string& message = "")
{
    using namespace std;

    if (!message.empty()) { cout << message << endl; }
    if (cin.fail()) { cin.clear(); }
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n').get();
}

// Если ввести число, пробел и символ(ы), то будет следующий запрос значений выполнен 2 раза, 
// если он зациклен, как в этой функции. Самый ненадёжный вариант.
template <
    typename NumericType,
    typename TParam,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<NumericType>::value, NumericType>::type
>
NumericType getUserInputEx(const std::string& message = "",
    std::function<bool(TParam)> const& predicate = [](const TParam) { return true; })
{
    using namespace std;

    NumericType number = 0;
    while (true) // Бесконечный цикл, который внутри прерывается по условию
    {
        cout << message; // Вывод сообщения для пользователя
        cin >> number;   // Ввод значения пользователем

        if (!cin.fail()) // Если ввели число, а значит поток не в состоянии ошибки, то завершаем цикл
        {
            // Вызываем переданное лямбда-выражение. 
            // Если условие пройдено, то не переходим к новой итерации.
            if (!predicate(number))
            {
                continue; // Переходим к новой итерации цикла пропуская код ниже
            }

            break; // Прерывает цикл
        }
        cin.clear(); // Сбрасываем состояние ошибки
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        // На следующей итерации цикла снова запросим ввод, так как была ошибка
    }
    return number; // Возвращаем из функции результат в место вызова функции
}

uint32_t getUserInputAsUInt32(const std::string& message = "")
{
    using namespace std;

    uint32_t number = 0;
    while (true) // Бесконечный цикл, который внутри прерывается по условию
    {
        cout << message; // Вывод сообщения для пользователя
        cin >> number;   // Ввод значения пользователем
        if (!cin.fail()) // Если ввели число, а значит поток не в состоянии ошибки, то завершаем цикл
        {
            break; // Прерывает цикл
        }
        cin.clear(); // Сбрасываем состояние ошибки
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        // На следующей итерации цикла снова запросим ввод, так как была ошибка
    }
    return number; // Возвращаем из функции результат в место вызова функции
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    const uint32_t MIN_ARRAY_SIZE = 1u;
    const uint32_t MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 50u;
    uint32_t sum = 0u, composition = 1u;

    // Формируем сообщение для пользователя
    const string message = "Введите кол-во элементов в массиве в диапазоне от " +
        to_string(MIN_ARRAY_SIZE) + " до " + to_string(MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) + ": ";

    // Это называется лямбда-выражение. Здесь используется для того, чтобы можно было написать
    // одну универсальную функцию (getUserInputEx<T1, T2>), которая может не прекращать запрашивать 
    // ввод у пользователя, пока не будет удовлетворено условие предиката isNumberValid. То 
    // есть для разных случаев использования можно задавать своё новое условие.
    // Вызывается на каждой итерации цикла внутри функции getUserInputAsInt
    const function<bool(uint32_t)> isNumberValid = [&](const uint32_t number)
    {
        // В number будет последнее введённое пользователем число. Здесь мы решаем прошло ли оно
        // наше условие, в котором мы определям согласны ли мы на такое значение от пользователя.
        return number >= MIN_ARRAY_SIZE && number <= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
    };

    const uint32_t numberOfValues = getUserInputEx<uint32_t, uint32_t>(message, isNumberValid);

    uint32_t array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
    {
        array[i] = getUserInputAsUInt32("Ввод элемента array[" + to_string(i) + "] = ");
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << endl;
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    cout << "Среднее арифметическое = " << sum / numberOfValues << endl;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numberOfValues; ++i)
    {
        composition *= array[i];
    }

    cout << "Произведение = " << composition << endl;

    pause("Нажмите Enter, чтобы продолжить...");
    return 0;
}
```

Ещё такой вариант, который будет запрашивать до тех пор, пока не будет введено только число без лишних символов, пробелов и т.д.

**Пример 2** Проходит все тест кейсы. Самый надёжный вариант, который возвращает результат, только если ввели значение строго из запрашиваемого диапазона без лишних символов и пробелов

```
uint32_t getUserInputAsUInt32(const std::string& message, uint32_t min, uint32_t max)
{
    using namespace std;
    assert(min < max);

    uint32_t number = 0u;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << message;

        string input;
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input.length() == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        const int64_t digitsCount = count_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
            [](unsigned char ch) { return isdigit(ch); });

        if (static_cast<size_t>(digitsCount) == input.length())
        {
            const uint64_t temp = stoull(input);
            if (temp <= numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
            {
                number = static_cast<uint32_t>(temp);
                if (number >= min && number <= max)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

**Пример 3** Проходит НЕ все тест кейсы - можно ввести число и после него пробел и далее что угодно, в итоге получим число. Что, кстати, тоже как вариант, если нет строго требования, чтобы пользователь осознаннов ввёл всё правильно и строго именно число без лишних символов после него

```
uint32_t getUserInputAsUInt32Ex(const std::string& message = "",
    std::function<bool(uint32_t)> const& predicate = [](const uint32_t) { return true; })
{
    using namespace std;

    uint32_t number = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << message;

        string input;
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input.length() == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        const uint64_t temp = strtoll(input.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
        if (temp <= numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
        {
            number = static_cast<uint32_t>(temp);
            if (predicate(number))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Если в строке есть что-то после числа, это игнорируется и повторный ввод не запрашивается. Так и задумано?

Comment: Нет. Советы и исправления приветствуются. Странно, но почему-то я так не тестил. И в правду, если после числа что-то есть, то поведение немного не то, какое ожидал я. Задумано так: что угодно ввели, если это не число, то снова повторяем вопрос. В идеале, если есть число и после него что-то ещё, то забираем число, остальное игнорируем.

Comment: Много раз обновил и вопрос и ответ. Комментарии выше уже не актуальны