# В каком случае вводить массив с клавиатуры, а в каком его генерировать

Tags: c++, массивы

При изучении `С++` часто сталкиваюсь с задачами, которые основываются, как на одномерных массивах, так и на многомерных.
Возник вопрос следующего характера : в каких случаях массив лучше ввести с клавиатуры, а в каких его лучше сгенерировать?

Comment: Имхо, бессмысленный вопрос. Если учебная задача **не** состоит в том, чтобы обработать пользовательский ввод или научиться работать с ГСЧ, то какая разница? Делайте как хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря для чего?
Если вам надо что-то тестировать - создайте файл с данными и зачитывайте оттуда.

Ввод данных с клавиатуры нужен разве что, когда вам нечасто (чаще всего одноразово) требуется проверить небольшой набор данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если мне нужно проверить что-то в массиве. Например, является ли матрица единичной или является ли она "магическим квадратом"? Как в данном случае лучше заполнять массив? Путем ввода, генерации или же взять из файла его значения? Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы пишите некоторую функцию (например функцию проверки на единичность), но хотите проверить работу функции, тогда я бы сделал так: 1) маленькие тестовые матрицы вбил бы напрямую в код (единичную и не единичную) и проверил как работает функция 2) потом сгенерировал бы матрицу огромного размера и записал бы ее в файл - чтобы проверить результат работы функции глазами.

Дело в том, что очень мало задач, где требовалось бы вбивать что-то с клавиатуры - если данных мало, их можно в код жестко вбить (временно), а если много - файл/генерация (если известен закон), руками вбивать - неэффективно

Answer (score 1):

Нужно написать функцию или метод класса, если речь об ООП, которая запрашивает ввод данных от пользователя. Написать все нужные функции/методы для работы с массивами. А далее уже по обстоятельствам, если нужно запросить ввод, то вызываем функцию запроса ввода данных от пользователя, если не нужно, то получаем данные каким-то другим методом.

В итоге есть функции:

- Запроса ввода от пользователя, которая возвращает массив нужных
  значений (функция ещё и контролирует корректность введённых данных)
- Функция чтения данных из файла
- Функция генерации случайных значений

Далее в проекте ты вызываешь нужные функции в нужных местах. Всё зависит от твоей задачи. Нет способа лучше или хуже. Есть способы получения значений, зависящие от твоей задачи.

Вот, как пример (посмотри внимательно функцию `main`, как я там запрашиваю значения):
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939747/185863